# Grid overlapping and z index, I cannot select my content

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I need help with making a nav bar on my grid on a portfolio that I'm coding. I have two main sections a nav bar and main content, I want it to be a full-height scroll page with a static nav bar.

Since, they are overlapping in the first row, if I put my content infront in the z-index I am able to scroll the content but not select the navbar. Same problem in reverse.

Am I doing this correctly?

IN SHORT: I want my content to scroll edge to edge vertically in the middle while having a static nav bar. Since they are currently overlapping in the same grid I cannot access either one.

If I set my content to the a second row, my content doesnt reach the top as the navbar cuts out my content.

I tried making it into absolute in the Nav but I feel like I'm breaking conventions

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr .5fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-area: 100%;
}

.topnav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  min-height: 8vh;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

#scrollcontent {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="About.html">
     Me
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navlinks">
      <a href="#work" id="work">WORK</a>
      <a href="About.html" id="about">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div id="scrollcontent">
      <div class='column'>
        <div class='projimg1'>
          <img src="img/Hero%20image%20for%20projects(larger).png" alt="Project" class="responsive">
          <div class="proj1text">
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <h3>Lorem Ispem abcdefg hijklmnop</h3>
          </div>
          /* list of projects */
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Two `</div></div>` is missing from the end ?

Comment: If you have an element in front of other elements and you don't want the former to be clicked on you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

If you use `z-index` to put `.navlinks` on top and `#scrollcontent` underneath, then the top row of #scrollcontent can scroll under the .navlinks bar. If you put a `padding-top` or `margin-top` on the #scrollcontent, **the same height as .navlinks**, then the first row won't be able to go under the .navlinks, because the top padding/margin is there.

Also to ensure the content touches the edges of the browser view, consider using `html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`. I think [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) does this automatically.